# MySQL database backup using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, backup, database-backups

I have used the following to check if `exec()` is enabled  on my server:

```
public function exec_enabled() {
  $disabled = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
  return !in_array('exec', $disabled);
}
```

And I found out that it was enabled on my server. Now I am trying to run the following, and the database isn't getting backed up:

```
exec('mysqldump --user=foo --password=bar --host=localhost foobar > backup.sql');
```

I have also tried

```
exec('mysqldump -u foo -p bar foobar > backup.sql');
```

But it didn't work either. Also, I am not getting any errors (error reporting is on). Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try this `exec('mysqldump -ufoo -pbar foobar > backup.sql');`. Don't leave space after user and password

Comment: use `system("mysqldump -ufoo -pbar foobar > backup.sql");` instead of exec.

Comment: Already tried that dear. I have posted this after trying with `exec()`, `shell_exec()` and `system()`

Comment: exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -uusername-ppassword databasename | gzip -9 > /path/to/backupfile.gz"); for linux

Comment: Password field: -pbar instead of -p bar

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export MySQL database using PHP only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195493/export-mysql-database-using-php-only)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
mysqldump -u username -ppass_word database_name table_name > path/sql_file_name.sql
```

Comment: The -p option tells MySQL to prompt for a password

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
exec('mysqldump -u foo --password=bar --host=localhost foobar > backup.sql');
```

Answer (score 0):

In *nix systems, use the WHICH command to show the location of the mysqldump, try this :

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'test';
$mysqldump=exec('which mysqldump');

$backup_file = $dbname .'.gz';
$command = "$mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass ".
           "test_db | gzip > $backup_file";

exec($command);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

putting the complete path to mysql dump seems to work

```
exec('complete\path\to\mysqldump.exe -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASE_NAME > output_folder_path/filename.sql');
```